# The reference issued for the continuing "in" OR "on" master degree?

Tags: american-english

I do not know which version is correct. Should I use *article* **"on"** or **"in"**?

> The reference issued for the continuing ***in*** master degree

OR

> The reference issued for the continuing ***on*** master degree?

Comment: A full sentence would help. What do you mean by "article"? "on" and "in" are not articles.

Comment: Someone issues a reference for you to continue in a **Master's** degree program?

Comment: A reference to support your application *for* a Master's degree course?